# $casts, array data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using $casts to save data in array to database. I have an issue with that.

How can i push data to an existing array in the database? 
For example i have already an array of data in my db column like: `["some_data", "another_el"]` and so on and in the Controller i want to push in this array in db some other data from input.

```
$brand = Brand::find($request->input('brand'));

        $brand->model = $request->input('model');
        $brand->update();
```

Pushing data like this.

Comment: Do you want to update in DB specified fields of array db datatype? Array Casting in Laravel only serializes data to JSON in setter and reserializes to php array in getter.

Comment: Yes, i want to push data to an existing array in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with Eloquent's Mass Assignment functions (update, create, etc). You must pull down your field, change it, then save the model.

```
$collection = collect($brand->field);
$collection->push($myNewData);
$brand->field = $collection->toJson();
$brand->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**

```
    $brand = Brand::find($request->input('brand'));

    $brand->model = array_merge($brand->model, [$request->input('model')]);
    $brand->update();
```

**Way 2** (my favorite because it encapsulates the logic)

```
    $brand = Brand::find($request->input('brand'));

    $brand->addModel($request->input('model'));
    $brand->update();
```

And on Entity:

```
    public function addModel($value)
    {
            $this->model = array_merge($this->model, [$value]);
    }
```

**Optional**

And on Entity (instead [$casts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)):

```
    public function setModelAttribute($value)
    {
            $this->attributes['model'] = json_encode($value);
    }

    public function getModelAttribute($value)
    {
            return json_decode($value, true);
    }
```

Comment: Dont do like that in Laravel) use [$casts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Comment: @pwnz22 The mutators can be a alternative to $casts (i edited the answer).